# Mapping through all images in firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web, firebase-storage

I've started to learn firebase, so I need to map and display all images from my storage. I know how to download and display only one image with its' path

```
const fireBaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

function App() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const func = async () => {
      const storage = getStorage(fireBaseApp);
      const download = ref(storage, "logo.png");
      await getDownloadURL(download).then((x) => {
        setUrl(x);
      });
    };
    func();
  }, []);

  return(
    <>
      <img src={url}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

So can anybody explain me, how to map through all images ? Thank you !

Comment: Like all images in a folder?

Comment: @Dharmaraj  I have one bucket in firebase storage, without folders, and all images are lying in this bucket, so i need to display them all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`listAll()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files#list_all_files) function to list all files in a directory or path.

```
import { getStorage, ref, listAll } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();

// Create a reference under which you want to list
const listRef = ref(storage, '/'); // replace path if needed

listAll(listRef)
  .then((res) => {
    res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
      // All the items under listRef.
      // Can get download URL for each item here
    });
  })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works at least for log data, I'll try to import it into other functions, can I ask you there if smth goes wrong ?

Comment: @DaniilGalitskii you're welcome. Unsure what you mean by import into other functions. Yes you can but if the new queries are unrelated to original question it'll be best to post a new one.